# Moving data from kernel buffer to userspace buffer in interrupt handler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

Newbie to Linux Kernel and driver development here.

I have data along with an interrupt coming in from a pcie device. Every time an interrupt is detected I want the driver to copy the data from a buffer (located in the driver) to a large buffer in userspace. The user app shall not "poll" the driver for new data.

Currently my interrupt handler attempts to `copy_to_user()` the data over to userspace. This however fails. `copy_to_user()` always returns *n*, where *n* is the number of bytes I wish to copy. My guess is the invocation of the interrupt handler causes context switching causing the copy to fail?

How should I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If the app doesn't poll, how does it know when new data shows up in the buffer? Does the driver send it a signal?

Comment: @Barmar The user app reads a register in the pcie device which signals that the device has already sent the data to the host.

Comment: Too broad. We are not a consulting site, but for **specific** questions show your code and point out what/why is not working..As a sidenote: if you have the option (e.g. an FPGA), use DMA in your device to copy the data to buffers.

Comment: You should never use copy_to_user in interrupt handler, which will make interrupt sleep. Deal interrupt should use the regular way, top-half, bottom-half, read LDD will be helpful

Comment: Never ever allow user to direcly communicate with pci device registers.

Answer (score 4):

`copy_to_user()` must be run in the context of the user-space process, because different processes have different address spaces. Furthermore, if the memory happens to be swapped out, `copy_to_user()` must read it back in, which requires file I/O and sleeping, which cannot be done from inside an interrupt handler.

In general, any buffers you use in an interrupt handler must be controlled (i.e., allocated) by the driver itself. If you want to give some user-space program access to that buffer, implement mmap().

In practice, it is typically the application's job to copy data from the DMA buffer to a larger buffer.

Comment: In regards to your last comment: "...it is typically the application's job to copy data from the DMA buffer to a larger buffer." Should I use the interrupt handler to let the user app know that new data has arrived and needs to be copied? Say via something like netlink?

Comment: You have to use the same mechanism regardless of whether the application accesses the DMA buffer or the bigger buffer.